# Basic probability question that is getting me confused!

Tags: probability

An expert sharpshooter misses a target 10 percent of the time.

Question:
"What is the probability that the first miss comes after the 3rd shot?"

Is this as simple as $(0.9)^3 \cdot 0.1$?

Comment: Just $(0.9)^3$ if the miss can be on the 4th shot, 5th, etc.

Comment: Do you mean on the 4th shot or on any shot after the 3rd???

Comment: Well that is what is getting me confused. My calculation is for a miss after the 3rd shot. How would you calculate it for any shot after the 3rd?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the probability that the first miss comes on the 4th shot, your answer of $(0.9)^3 \cdot 0.1$ is correct.

However, if you want the probability that it comes any time after the 3rd shot that is      $(0.9)^3$ as user66345 said.